# How to delete the the next word or remainder of a line in insert mode

Tags: neovim

New to vim/gvim, but I know that if I use `<C-w>` in insert mode, I can delete the word behind the cursor and from the beginning of the line to the cursor with `<C-u>`. Is there an easy way to do the rest forward of the character? How about to the end of the block? I try to use native commands as far as possible before adding a mapping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Insert mode is best used for just that, **inserting text**. While there are a few exceptions (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> being among them), most text manipulation should occur in Normal mode.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> will drop you into Normal mode and let you execute one Normal mode command, then return to Insert mode. You could do the following:

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to drop to Normal mode for one command, then <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to delete the rest of the word after the cursor, or <kbd>D</kbd> to delete the rest of the line, leaving you in Insert mode at the current cursor position.

---

Relevant Help:

```
:h i_CTRL-O
:h Insert
:h Normal
```